# Disable or remove YouTube movie recommendations

Tags: search, youtube

When I search for "movie 2010 trailers" to view trailers of movies that came out in 2010, I get flooded with recommendations to buy YouTube's movies and only 3 results are actual YouTube videos.

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=movie+2010+trailers

How can I remove this spam from my search results?

Answer (score 1):

Changing your filter to WebM should do the trick seeing that all videos are eventually converted to WebM. The promoted videos should now be removed applying this filter.